# EF Code First one to one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I have the following situation:

```
public class User
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   // ...
   public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Street { get; set; }
   public string ZipCode { get; set; }
   // ...
   public int UserID { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to setup the fluent mapping. I tried this:

```
void Map( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    var entityConfiguration = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
    entityConfiguration.HasKey( i => i.ID ).Property( i => i.ID ).HasColumnName( "UserID" );
    entityConfiguration.HasRequired(i => i.Address)
      .WithOptional(i => i.User);
    entityConfiguration.ToTable( "MyUser" );
}
```

But it's no good. It generates SQL that tries to join `User.UserID = Address.AddressID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF is creating the correct relation for a one-to-one mapping. Your own column naming's may have confused you.

A one-to-one relation is defined as follows

```
User Table            Address Table
----------            -------------
UserId PK             UserID PK, FK
Name                  ZipCode
```

The primary key of child table (Address) will also be the foreign key to the parent table (User)

If you are going to include `UserID` column in `Address` table and make it a foreign key to `User` table then this will be a one-to-many relation not a one-to-one.

Comment: I want my `User` table to have zero or one `Address`. I have a unique constraint on the `Address` table for this.

Comment: In this case make the mapping like this: entityConfiguration.HasOptional(i => i.Address).WithRequired(i => i.User);

Comment: That doesn't work. That generates the wrong SQL. It's what I have already.

Comment: What you have is the correct SQL for one-to-one. Read my answer again.